# How to set params for libvirt python api setBlockIoTune?

Tags: python, libvirt

I need set kvm virtual machine's disk IoTune by using python libvirt. After searching, i found a method "setBlockIoTune" at libvirt.py, it just call c api virDomainSetBlockIoTune,

```
int virDomainSetInterfaceParameters (virDomainPtr domain,
                 const char * device,
                 virTypedParameterPtr params,
                 int nparams,
                 unsigned int flags)
```

Here is the problem, I can't find how to set a value for "virTypedParameterPtr params" in in python livirt. The [doc](http://openstack-repo.cisco.com/openstack//cisco/pkgs/libvirt/docs/html/libvirt-libvirt.html#virDomainSetBlockIoTune) does't talk about it.

Please help me, Thanks!!

orz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just call libvirt python api "blockIoTune(dev)" to get a result, modify it then pass to setBlockIoTune.

result of blockIoTune(dev):

> {'write_bytes_sec': 0L, 'total_iops_sec': 0L, 'read_iops_sec': 0L, 'read_bytes_sec': 0L, 'write_iops_sec': 0L, 'total_bytes_sec': 0L}

Hope this could help someone :)